# Tips for golfing in Erlang

Tags: code-golf, tips

Does anybody have tips for golfing in Erlang? I'm looking for specific things that can be applied to Erlang, not any language. I know we already have tips for Elixir, but that is different.

As usual, please post separate tips in separate answers.

Answer (score 1):

### Use the ending conditions

Suppose you have a function reversing a list:

```
r([H|T])->[T]++r(H);r([])->[].
```

Since this is the only condition left, this can be golfed into:

```
r([H|T])->r(T)++[H];r(_)->[].
```

Or, since this is an identity function:

```
r([H|T])->r(T)++[H];r(I)->I.
```

You can also abuse the wild-cards in if statements. E.g.

```
if A<B->A;true->B end.
```

This can be golfed into:

```
if A<B->A;_->B end.
```